# what's domain in the dashboard of Ubuntu Openstack

Tags: juju, openstack, cloud

I am new to OpenStack and recently I am learning to use it. After I successfully install OpenStack by following this link: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/try-openstack

At 3rd step, it said, "default username “admin” and password “OpenStack”. However, when I entered the dashboard, I saw 3 entries: domain/username/password. Please see
[the screenshot of dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDtEq.jpg)

I cannot leave the "domain" with a blank but I really don't know what "domain" it is here. I searched online and only found some infos about functionalities about the domain of OpenStack.

Please help! Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just figured it out...

the domain that worked for me is "admin_domain".

I got it from /etc/keystone/keystone.conf inside the keystone machine.

Do "juju status" to figure out in which machine keystone is deployed

```
Unit                      Workload  Agent  Machine  Public address   Ports              Message
keystone/0*               active    idle   0/lxd/1  192.168.100.217  5000/tcp           Unit is ready
```

Then ssh to it and cat the file

```
juju ssh 0/lxd/1
sudo cat /etc/keystone/keystone.conf
```

The last lines show the domain and user:

```
[ldap]
[resource]
admin_project_domain_name = admin_domain
admin_project_name = admin
```

Comment: thank you! It works for me. It seems the default domain is always "admin_domain".

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be the most common answer, but mine was a bit more difficult.
I ran this command:

```
juju run --unit keystone/0 leader-get admin_passwd
```

and this was the password for the admin account.
The domain was "admin_domain" from above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you used the wrong IP address.

Please run `juju status` and find the IP address of openstack-dashboard service and go to the `http://<IP-Address>/horizon/auth/login/`. Please try `http` and `https` I didn't remember the right protocol

Comment: thank you. I do use the right IP address and the answer from @miguelcostaUI works!